# JEE6: Custom Realm vs ResourceFilter - which one is better for REST resource authentication?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, restful-authentication

I have a JEE6 application, residing on Glassfish 3.1.1, which provides service to remote clients via a number of REST resources. Some of the resources require authentication, others don't.

Currently I'm protecting the secure resources with HTTP Basic Authentication, implemented as a custom realm / LoginModule. If the authentication fails, the login module throws a `LoginException`, Glassfish maps that to HTTP 401. If the authentication is successful, the resources can access the `userPrincipal` in the `securityContext`.

While it works, it does annoy me that I cannot intercept the `LoginException`. My clients expect xml or json; in the HTTP 401 body, Glassfish gives them text/html. All other application exceptions I can intercept with an `ExceptionMapper`, just not the LoginException.

At the moment I'm thinking about replacing the Custom Realm with a `ResourceFilter`, where I would do the HTTP Basic authentication manually. I would expect that if I throw an exception here, it's gonna get intercepted and mapped / marshalled properly.

My questions are:

- Is it a good idea to use a `ResourceFilter` for authentication? What about performance?
- How would I let the REST resource know, who just got authenticated (who's the userPrinicipal)?

Comment: Btw, I have implemented it as a ResourceFilter and an Injectable UserProvider. If anyone is interested, I'm happy to post the code. Doesn't answer my questions if it's a good idea though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but anyway...

Its the container who does the authentication so it will never reach your resource. Personally I like the container managed authentication approach because it nicely separates the authentication from the application.

If you want to use a ResourceFilter you can access the SecurityContext from the request. This contains the Principal. From there you could populate e.g. an ApplicationConfig object which is accessible throughout the application.

Performance depends on the authentication implementation. I guess the overhead when using a ResourceFilter is minimal. If required you could always use a session cookie to keep the session to prevent authentication again.

Comment: I should have closed the question, since it's not an issue anymore. I'm doing it exactly as you say with `ResourceFilter` and `SecurityContext`. In a `ResourceFilter` I have perfect control over the exception btw..